# Look and say sequence

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to make a look and say sequence ant my code so far only works as it should when I have the 'realCounter' set to 2 or less and don't understand why. Thanks for any help! Here is my main :

```
        string number = "1";          
        string[] tempStore = new string[2];

        int realCounter = 0;

        while (realCounter < 2)
        {
            int counter = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (number[i] == number[i + 1])
                    {
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    tempStore[0] = number[i].ToString();
                    number = counter.ToString();
                    number = number + tempStore[0];
                }
            }
            realCounter++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(number);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

I've been changing the line with the while loop from realCounter < 2 to realCounter < 3 and the program doesn't perform as it should

Comment: Why is tempStore an array?  You never do anything with it beyond tempStore[0].  I don't recommend using exceptions as flow control.

Comment: If you limit your loop variable's max value to `i < number.Length - 1`, then there is no possibility for an exception and you can get rid of the `try/catch/tempStore` stuff.

Comment: In future questions, be sure to indicate WHAT the problem is. Statements like 'does't' perform as it should' are useless as no one here knows what you intend it to do. I shouldn't have to google to figure out the intent of your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are specifically checking to ensure realCounter < 2 as a condition of your while loop

Comment: oh no sorry, I've been changing the variable for testing purposes. When I change it to any greater number it doesn't perform as it should

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't perform as it should"?  Are you getting an index out of bounds exception?  Does it run, but give different results than you're expecting.  Describe what it is you think should be happening and what actually is happening

Answer (score 0):

```
            try
            {
                if (number[i] == number[i + 1])
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                tempStore[0] = number[i].ToString();
                number = counter.ToString();
                number = number + tempStore[0];
            }
```

You are only updating your `number` variable when you encounter an exception. You only encounter an exception when `number[i + 1]` hits an IndexOutOfBounds exception. So you're only updating `number` with the LAST sequence it encounters, and you're dropping all the rest.